# Adding header makes page not showing image

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using pChart to create some bar graphics. With some checkboxes the users can select which ids will be shown in the graph.

I need this to be not refreshing site, not iframe, not ajax. First I will explain my work and then go back to the title, the header problem.

I have 1 html file and 1 php file. In the first one, javascript is used to call the php function that create the graph. And that is working fine, the only issue is that I can not show the generated image, because the image has errors, but that's not true, when I go to open the generated image is shown perfect. Here is the code:

HTML + JS:

```
<input checked="checked" name="ids" id="id_1" value="1" type="checkbox">
<input checked="checked" name="ids" id="del_2" value="2" type="checkbox">
<input checked="checked" name="ids" id="del_3" value="3" type="checkbox">   

<input type="button" id="generarImg" name="generarImg" value="Generar Grafico" onClick="javascript: generarImg()" />
    <div id="barGraph"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function generarImg(){
            var checks = '';
            $("input:checkbox[name=del]:checked").each(function(){
                if(checks == ''){
                    checks = ($(this).val());
                } else {
                    checks = checks + "," + ($(this).val());
                }
            });
            document.getElementById('barGraph').innerHTML = "<img src='bargraph.php?ids=" + checks + "' alt='' title='Bar Graph' />";
        }
    </script>
```

PHP:

```
$db=db_connect(MYDB_CONN_STRING2);
$query_res=db_query($db,"
select id,value from table1
limit 3");

    $ids = $_GET['ids'];
    $ids = explode(",", $ids);
    for ($i=0;$i<count($query_res); $i++) {
        if(in_array($query_res[$i]["id"],$ids)){
            $tableids[]=$query_res[$i]["id"];
            $values[]=$query_res[$i]["value"];
        }
    }
    BarGraph($tableids, $values);

    function BarGraph($ids, $values){
        //Set the data for the graph.
        $DataSet = new pData;
        $DataSet->AddPoint($values,"Values");
        $DataSet->SetYAxisName("Values");
        $DataSet->SetXAxisName("Ids");      
        $DataSet->AddAllSeries();

        $DataSet->AddPoint($ids,"Ids");
        $DataSet->SetAbsciseLabelSerie("Ids");

        //Draw the graph area.
        $Test = new pChart(900,300);
        $Test->setFontProperties("graphs/pChart/Fonts/tahoma.ttf",10);
        $Test->setGraphArea(100,100,700,250);
        $Test->drawGraphArea(252,252,252);
        $Test->drawScale($DataSet->GetData(),$DataSet->GetDataDescription(),SCALE_NORMAL,150,150,150,TRUE,0,0,TRUE,0);
        $Test->drawGrid(4,TRUE,230,230,230,255);

        //Draw the graph and then add some titles.
        $Test->drawBarGraph($DataSet->GetData(),$DataSet->GetDataDescription());

        $Test->setFontProperties("graphs/pChart/Fonts/tahoma.ttf",8);
        $Test->drawLegend(45,35,$DataSet->GetDataDescription(),255,255,255);
        $Test->setFontProperties("graphs/pChart/onts/tahoma.ttf",10);
        $Test->drawTitle(60,22,"My pretty graph",50,50,50,585);

        //Render the graph to .png, THIS WORKS FINE!
        $Test->Render("BarGraph.png");

        //HERE IS THE ISSUE
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        echo '<img src="BarGraph.png" alt="" title="Bar Graph"/>';
    }
```

So, if I `echo` the image without the `header('Content-type: image/png');` in the php file (going to that link) the image is shown. But not in the HTML, because I'm giving to an img tag, a php file. So I add the header, but when adding it, the php file goes all black with this message: 'The image "name of image" can not be shown, because it contain errors". And the HTML file is not showing anything in that img tag.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try using imagepng??@AleOtero93

Comment: yes, same results in HTML... in PHP not even showing the image. @SubinThomas

Comment: This image is saved?? @AleOtero93

Comment: yes, is saved and whenever I change it with the function is updated correctly @SubinThomas

Comment: That's right, allready tried adding another `<img src="image rout" />` after calling the php function, but did not work @SubinThomas

Comment: Check my answer. I expect it should solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use `readfile()`?

So then your code would be:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
readfile('BarGraph.png');
```

I just tested it out myself on my own domain.

The code I used was the following:

**testimage.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function pullPic(){
      var val = document.getElementById('choice').value;
      document.getElementById('picture').innerHTML = "<img src='testimage.php?duck=" + val + "' />";
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="choice">
      <option value="duck1">duck 1</option>
      <option value="duck2">duck 2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" onclick="pullPic();">Click</button>
    <div id="picture"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**testimage.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['duck'])) {
    header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
    if($_REQUEST['duck'] == 'duck1') {
        readfile('duck.jpg');
    } else if($_REQUEST['duck'] == 'duck2') {
        readfile('duck2.jpg');
    }
}
?>
```

This means you don't need to use AJAX, refresh or iframe.
You can check it out [here for the time being](http://website-bouwers.com/testimage.html)

Comment: It is indeed possible to show an image without ajax. Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: document.getElementById('barGraph').innerHTML = "<img src='bargraph.php?ids=" + checks + "' alt='' title='Bar Graph' />";      See this line in his JS. He is calling a php file, and a function need to run inside.

Comment: I don't think it is possible without AJAX as you need to run function in PHP. @JiFus

Comment: @SubinThomas if he changes the html, the source attribute will change. This means the link to the php page will change. Because this page will run once you put it in the source it should dynamically changes the file to output if I'm not mistaking.

Comment: *"I need this to be not refreshing site, not iframe, not ajax."*     Then how it is possible for an onclick event??

Comment: I fixed it on my own site just now, you can have a look [here](http://website-bouwers.com/testimage.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't work... Still same error

Comment: @JiFus  Problem solved. Check my answer. Using dataURL

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and I could do this by dataURL. So in my code, instead of `render`, I used `autoOutput`. So my code is as follows.

In php,

```
$myPicture->autoOutput($target);  //save the file
```

And in JS, as same as you used.

```
document.getElementById('picture').innerHTML = "<img src='<phpfile including location>' />";
```

This one is working for me.

Comment: could you please give me the `autoOutput` code? Its not in my pchart vertion

Comment: I used pchart2.1.4  @AleOtero93  autoOutput will show image directly. See my edit.